# How can we select an element's parameter using jQuery

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

How can we update the `<param name='wmode' value='WINDOW'` to `<param name='wmode' value='TRANSPARENT'` using jQuery?

After multiple attempts I've ended up using the following, but the element is not selected:

```
$(window).load(function () {
    $("param[name='wmode'").attr('value', 'transparent')
});
```

Background:
The `$(window).load(...` function is necessary. I've tested this same snippet omitting `[name='wmode']` and every param is overwritten to `<param name="wmode" value="transparent"...`, adding the `[name='wmode']` breaks the selector somehow.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a typo in your selector. Update your code as follows:

```
$('param[name="wmode"]').prop('value', 'transparent');
```

Also, you might want to hook into the DOMReady function, not the `window.load` event. Use the following code:

```
$(function() {  
    $('param[name="wmode"]').prop('value', 'transparent');
});
```

Also, note the use of [`prop()`](http://api.jquery.com/prop/), rather than `attr()`. Here's the jQuery documentation:

> The difference between *attributes* and *properties* can be important in
>   specific situations. **Before jQuery 1.6**, the [`.attr()`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) method sometimes
>   took property values into account when retrieving some attributes,
>   which could cause inconsistent behavior. **As of jQuery 1.6**, the `.prop()`
>   method provides a way to explicitly retrieve property values, while
>   `.attr()` retrieves attributes.

Comment: This worked great! Thanks for the Attr vs Prop correction and background.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
$(function() {  
    $('param[name="wmode"]').prop('value', 'transparent');
});
```

Using [.prop()](http://api.jquery.com/prop/) function instead of attr()

> The difference between attributes and properties can be important in
>   specific situations. Before jQuery 1.6, the .attr() method sometimes
>   took property values into account when retrieving some attributes,
>   which could cause inconsistent behavior. As of jQuery 1.6, the .prop()
>   method provides a way to explicitly retrieve property values, while
>   .attr() retrieves attributes.

Comment: @DrCord:- Yes..I have updated my answer. The link of the .prop() was the best answer for that! P.S. Although I know I got beaten up by BenM by seconds :)